# How to call a class from a fragment

Tags: java, android

I am making an alarm application which will notify on user provided time.
I am calling a class `MyAlarm` from my fragment `TimepickerFragment` but it is not passing to MyAlarm class.

Following is the code in my fragment:

```
public class TimepickerFragment extends Fragment {

Button SetTime;
TimePicker timePicker;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.timepickerfragment,null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    SetTime = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.settime);
    SetTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(
                    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                    timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                    0

            );

            setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new Room1Fragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }



        private void setAlarm(long timeInMillis) {

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


            Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), MyAlarm.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0 , intent, 0);


            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC , timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}

}
```

It should pass to this class:

```
    public class MyAlarm extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "MyAlarm Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(intent);



    }
}
```

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.haziqnaeem.settimer2">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyAlarm"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
</application>
```

Need Help

Comment: Have you registered `MyAlarm` as receiver in Manifest ?

Comment: Yes i did register.!

Comment: ok i added..!!!

Comment: Only for testing try to schedule alarm for 1 minute later using `set()`. Check if it works . As `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+1000,pendingIntent);`.

Comment: this code is working on a new project. but not working in a project where i want to use.. this project contains fragments. may be thats the issue.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand u well, you want when the times come, your device will alarm the user, but the class MyAlarm it's a WakefulBroadcastReceiver that's meen: " implementing a BroadcastReceiver that receives a device wakeup event and then passes the work off to a Service, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep during the transition " ==> from official docs.

Now, you have set the AlarmManager, so, from the pendingIntent lunch an Intent service for exemple that will fire a sound or notification or something like that, but know that an AlarmManager won't actually turn the screen on for you, so the WakefulBroadcastReceiver won't be called, you can instead use PowerManager with wakelock. 
And know also that WakefulBroadcastReceiver was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.

Comment: I also have a service java activity where i am playing notification sound

Comment: Okey, Hope I had been helpfull for you

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to declare your `MyAlarm` class in manifest file as follows

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyAlarm"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

with following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: Why `android:process=":remote"`?

Comment: done but still not working. The Toast in MyAlarm not showing

Comment: if your click listener is working in fragment, then alarm should be set too